# Provisioning windows jenkins agents via EC2 plugin

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to provision some dynamic jenkins agents via the EC2 plugin but I'm having some issues as it can't connect to WinRM:

`Waiting for password to be available. Sleeping 10s. Waiting for password to be available. Sleeping 10s. Connecting to (IP) with WinRM as Administrator Waiting for WinRM to come up. Sleeping 10s. Waiting for WinRM to come up. Sleeping 10s. Waiting for WinRM to come up. Sleeping 10s.`

Things I've tried:

1. Private and public subnets on VPC
2. Enabled all traffic in security groups
3. Disabling firewall on AMI
4. Configuring WinRM in AMI with custom powershell commands as described [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AppVeyorBYOC/1.0.167/Content/scripts%5CWindows%5Caws%5Cenable-winrm.ps1)
5. Waiting for a longer time won't help since I've left it more than 2 days
6. Tried on a local Jenkins instance thinking that'll change anything

Weirder thing is that connecting via WinRM works from a custom script via the controller so a script like the one below works but connecting via the jenkins UI (provisioning a node) doesn't.

```
import winrm
winrmSession = winrm.Session('IP', auth=('Administrator', 'password'))
commandResult = winrmSession.run_cmd("ipconfig")
print(commandResult.std_out)
```

Pasting below a list of parameters I've used to create the cloud in the plugin:

```
def slaveTemplateUsEast1Parameters = [
  ami:                           'ami-00531d3c1675b139b',
  associatePublicIp:             false,
  spotConfig:                    null,
  connectBySSHProcess:           true,
  connectUsingPublicIp:          false,
  customDeviceMapping:           '',
  deleteRootOnTermination:       true,
  description:                   'Dynamic Windows EC2 slaves in AWS',
  ebsOptimized:                  false,
  iamInstanceProfile:            '',
  idleTerminationMinutes:        '30',
  initScript:                    '', 
  instanceCapStr:                '2',
  javaPath:                      'java',
  jvmopts:                       '-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\\jenkins\\temp',
  labelString:                   'windows',
  launchTimeoutStr:              '',
  numExecutors:                  '1',
  unixData:                      new UnixData(null, null, null, sshPortToConnectWith, null),
  remoteFS:                      'C:\\jenkins',
  remoteAdmin:                   'Administrator',
  tmpDir:                        '', 
  securityGroups:                'sg-id',
  stopOnTerminate:               false,
  subnetId:                      'subnet-id',
  tags:                          new EC2Tag('Name', 'jenkins-worker'),
  type:                          't2.medium',
  useDedicatedTenancy:           false,
  useEphemeralDevices:           false,
  usePrivateDnsName:             false,
  userData:                      '',
  zone:                          'us-east-1a',
  metadataSupported:             true,
  metadataEndpointEnabled:       true,
  metadataTokensRequired:        false,
  metadataHopsLimit:             1,
  minimumNumberOfInstances:      0,
  minimumNumberOfSpareInstances: 0,
  maxTotalUses:                  -1,
  monitoring:                    false,
  t2Unlimited:                   false,
  connectionStrategy:            ConnectionStrategy.valueOf('PRIVATE_IP'),
  hostKeyVerificationStrategy:   HostKeyVerificationStrategyEnum.valueOf('OFF'),
  tenancy:                       Tenancy.valueOf('Default'),
  ebsEncryptRootVolume:          EbsEncryptRootVolume.valueOf('DEFAULT'),
  nodeProperties:                null
]
```